# Importing tasks to Rally

Tags: rally

Is there a way to import tasks into Rally? 
I know how to import user stories and defects from a csv file, and I see how to export tasks, but I can't find anything anywhere about importing tasks IN to Rally.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this through the Rally UI. It is a very popular feature request. I'd recommend registering your support for this feature by voting up this existing Idea out on Rally Ideas:

http://ideas.rallydev.com/ideas/D336

Alternatively, some customers have opted to write webservices scripts using Rally's developer toolkits/APIs:

http://developer.rallydev.com/help/rest-apis

To facilitate this functionality.

Comment: Import Tasks - to be released soon!

Answer (score 2):

i was able to import tasks by using the Rally Excel add-in.  the field must be identical to the schema and there are a few required fields.  Note the Work Product field is how it knows which user story to import the tasks under (which is a bit odd -- not sure what they don't just use the user story #.). And Work Product is equivalent to the User Story Name

https://prod.help.rallydev.com/rally-add-excel

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do this without the Excel add-in.

Steps to import tasks:

1. In Rally, Click on ‘Track’ on the header and click ‘Tasks’ from the dropdown
2. Then click on ‘Actions’ on the right side and click ‘Import Tasks…’ from the dropdown
3. Browse to the file and click import

Remember to not put any commas in your Comma Separated Values (.csv) file.